# How secure is authentication in mysql protocol?

Tags: mysql, security, protocols

My users are using MS Access and ODBC connector to connect to my remote MySQL database. I wonder how secure this is, in the sense of possible password disclosure to 3rd party. Is the mysql protocol authentication safe to eavesdropping or even man-in-the-middle attacks? I would be quite happy with safety against eavesdropping. Note that my concern is only authentication, I'm not concerned about data disclosure.

Please don't reply that I should use SSL. I know this would be ideal however the setup doesn't seem very simple. Anyway, I would like to know what is the safety level of plain mysql protocol.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What is it that you want to be "*safe to eavesdropping or even man-in-the-middle attacks*"?  Your password, or your data?

The title of your question refers specifically to *authentication*.  MySQL does a reasonable job of protecting your password from eavesdroppers (it is not sent plaintext, and the use of a nonce defeats replay attacks). Citing  [MySQL protocol internals](http://web.archive.org/web/20120701044449/http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol#Password_functions):

> MySQL 4.1 and later
>
> Remember that mysql.user.Password stores SHA1(SHA1(password))
>
> - The server sends a random string (scramble) to the client
> - the client calculates:
>
>   - stage1_hash = SHA1(password), using the password that the user has entered.
>   - token = SHA1(scramble + SHA1(stage1_hash)) XOR stage1_hash
> - the client sends the token to the server
> - the server calculates
>
>   - stage1_hash' = token XOR SHA1(scramble + mysql.user.Password)
> - the server compares SHA1(stage1_hash') and mysql.user.Password
> - If they are the same, the password is okay.
>
> (Note SHA1(A+B) is the SHA1 of the concatenation of A with B.)
>
> **This protocol fixes the flaw of the old one, neither snooping on the
>   wire nor mysql.user.Password are sufficient for a successful
>   connection.** But when one has both mysql.user.Password and the
>   intercepted data on the wire, he has enough information to connect.

However, authenticated sessions continue in plaintext: an eavesdropper will be able to see all queries and results; and a MITM would be able to make alterations to the same.  As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-basics.html):

> By default, MySQL uses unencrypted connections between the client and the server. This means that someone with access to the network could watch all your traffic and look at the data being sent or received. They could even change the data while it is in transit between client and server.

Whilst you may not like the answer, SSL is *the tool* designed to defeat both data eavesdropping (how else can the communications be encrypted?) and MITM attacks (how else can either party verify that its peer is who it thinks it is?).  Indeed, if the mysql client-server protocol alone defeated these threats then there would be no reason to use mysql over SSL (and thus it would be unlikely to be a supported configuration).

Comment: *What do you mean by "safe to eavesdropping or even man-in-the-middle attacks"*: as you said, plain mysql protocol is not MITM safe, my concern now is only if authentication is safe to eavesdropping. If someone is eavesdropping, will he then able to gain enough information to authenticate to the mysql server? I don't mind if he's just watching the data... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Tomas: No, as my answer says, he will only see an encrypted form of a password hash which cannot be replayed due to the use of a nonce.  However, if able to manipulate packets, he could hijack the session to perform whatever commands he likes.

Comment: Excuse me, I haven't understood what you meant with "nonce". Is it a random string sent by the server?

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, it ensures that the client's response is different on each connection attempt and the correct response can only be predicted if the correct password hash is known.  See [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! The link to the mysql docs you posted was very useful, I completed your answer by including the very important part of it. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomas Thank you for adding the sha authentication exchange details to the answer! It's very helpful ! Btw, it's a pity that I couldn't find these details in the current Oracle's Mysql document.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: Yes, the protocol is safe from Eavesdropping and MITM attacks.

Only if the attacker manages to sniff an authentication attempt *AND* if the attacker knows the contents of mysql.user, then he can subsequently authenticate against the server. For example if you're using the same password on two different mysql servers and the attacker gains access to one of them, he can also connect to the second server.

Comment: Are you sure this protocol is safe from MITM? And I don't realize what you meant with the 2nd paragraph. Of course when attacker sniffs password, he can connect with it..