# Is it possible to hack my database by knowing the username and password (only) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, security

Is it possible for someone to hack a MySQL database by knowing (only) the username and the password for my database.

There is no phpMyAdmin to login from it and there is no way to do any SQL injection in the website (because I'm using Laravel).

Comment: It's not a hack - it's a feature. You can enable or disable remote access for a specific user. However - one would also need the address.

Comment: then if the feature is disable, no one can access to my database even if they know the password

Comment: I didn't say that! If you think, someone has username/password to access your DB who shouldn't, you should change them.

Comment: i'm not asking this question for my database, what is above is only an example  . there is an exploit work with some none expert laravel website and you can get the password for those website . and i need to know is it possible or not

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking, instead of adding comments. Maybe check security.stackexchange.com instead plain old stackoverflow.com

Comment: This question is a bit broad at the moment. What address is your database server listening to? If it is localhost/127.0.0.1 then you should be OK, since to connect to it, a cracker would need to first have an account on the box. If you listen on a server LAN address, that is fine too, assuming no hackers can connect to your LAN. However if you need to listen to a WAN/internet address, consider using a firewall to specify what can connect to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is quite similar to "Is it possible to break into my house with my door key?"

It depends on few things:

1. Which IP is your MySQL listening to? In your MySQL Config File `bind-address`, find the value.
2. For that specific username, did you enabled remote access for that user in MySQL?
3. Any Firewall rules to restrict remote MySQL connections?

By the way, using Laravel or any other frameworks does NOT guarantee anything on protecting from SQL injection. People can easily write a SQL injection vulnerable web page under any framework if they want.

You should:

- Implement your database related code properly and follow the instruction in the documentation.
- Set your MySQL users and their privilege in the right way.
- Do not expose your database to the public is recommended.

Last thing for your update, if you want to share your database with others. Not a big problem if you set the privilege correctly.

Comment: that exactly what I'm looking for . i'm asking about this not because someone have my user password . in some laravel website there is an exploit to take the password of the database if the programmer was not expert in this framework . because this i'm asking is it possible to enter to it or not .  thank you for your response man

Comment: @isams I forgot to mention. MySQL transfer it's data in plain text by default, which means, your queries and results can be seen and eavesdropping is very simple for you ISP or when the connection is not secure. Please refer to this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11192872/1796112  and the MySQL doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html